# CKEditor bulletlist (and orderedlist) behavior wrong when I cut it?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor and I love it.
but there's truble when I use bullet(ordered)list and cut it.

1.make list like below.

- List item1

  - List item2

    - List item3

2.then, cut text from end of "ListItem3" to start of "ListItem1"(not delete but cut using cmd + x).

3.ul(or ol) tag is remain like below.

- - 

remained HTML like this

```
<ul>
  <li>&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

can I avoid this behavior? or are there any workaroud?

Comment: Which browser are you using? In chrome it keeps only 1 level of the list (`ul > li`), which also seems wrong... but not the same way you get it. It looks like a bug.

Comment: @Dekel
Sorry for my late reply.
I use Chrome(ver. 54.0). And, it seems to be render second( or third) level o f the list.

Comment: Anyway - it looks like a bug :)